# Is there any implementation of Logging out of other browsers and devices in Flask?

Tags: python, session, flask, browser, logout

I have to implement a function in my website where there can only be one login per account. So, if a user logs into one browser, the others will automatically be logged out. I am using Flask for backend. Is there any such implementation in Flask, and if not, what are some ways by which I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any implementation. The first thing that comes to my mind is to modify the user model. You could add a column for `logged_in`, which get's changed to `True` when the user is logged in and to `False` if the user logs out/ the session is dropped.

You would need to check this attribute when verifying the user login. For further specific help consider posting an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your question.